# Loading data into HIVE to support front end application

Tags: hadoop

We have a datawarehousing application which we are planning to convert to Hadoop.

Currently, there are 20 feeds that we receive on daily basis and load this data into MySQL database.

As the data is getting large, we are planning to move to Hadoop for faster query processing.

As the first step we are planning to load the data into HIVE on a daily basis instead of MySQL.

Question:-
1.Can I convert Hadoop similar to a DWH application to process files on daily basis?
2.When I load the data in Master Node, will it be sync'd automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the size of your data. The Question is a bit complex but in general you will have to design your own pipeline.

1. If you are analyzing raw logs HDFS will be a good choice to start from. You can use Java, Python or Scala to schedule the Hive jobs on daily basis and use Sqoop if you still need some MySQL data.
2. In Hive you will have to create partitioned table to be synced and available upon query execution. Partition creation can be also scheduled.

I would suggest to go with Impala instead of Hive as it is more tunable, fault tolerant and easier to use.